# How do I customize the url path of a sub resource in angular-restmod

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-restmod

I have the following setup

```
angular.module('xyz').factory('Bike', function (restmod) {
    return restmod.model('/bikes').mix({
        BikeParts: { hasMany: "BikeParts" },
        $extend: {
            Record: {
                savePart: function (part) {
                    this.BikeParts.$create(part);
                },
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Now if I have a `bike` with id 1 calling `bike.savePart(part)` creates a POST request to `/bikes/1/bike-parts`. I want instead that it posts to `/bikes/1/parts/`. Is there a way to do this (without renaming the `BikeParts` entry in the call to `mix`)?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change the url by adding a `path` property in your hasMany relation.

So change `BikeParts: { hasMany: "BikeParts" }` to `BikeParts: { hasMany: "BikeParts", path: "parts" }` and your url should become `/bikes/1/parts/`.